# What real-world mountain was used in Where Eagles Dare?

Tags: film-location, where-eagles-dare

What is the real-world mountain that was used for filming the cable car scene in [*Where Eagles Dare*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065207/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie's [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Eagles_Dare) gives a list of all the filming locations:

> Filming:
>
> - the castle – Hohenwerfen Castle, Werfen, Austria; filmed in January 1968,
> - **cable car – Feuerkogel Seilbahn at Ebensee (Austria); filmed in January 1968**,
> - airport scenes – Flugplatz Aigen im Ennstal (Austria); filmed in early 1968. The exact place of filming is the "Fiala-Fernbrugg"
>     garrison, still used by HS Geschwader 2 and FlAR2/3rd Bat. of the
>     Austrian army. The big rocky mountain in the background of the
>     airfield is the Grimming mountains, about 40 km east from the "Hoher
>     Dachstein", or about 80 km east and 10 km south from Werfen,
> - other scenes – MGM-British Studios, Borehamwood, England; filmed in spring 1968

And the [Wikipedia article of that location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebensee) in turn says, that it's indeed the mountain that's called ***Feuerkogel***:

> Since 1927 an aerial tramway built by the Bleichert engineering company runs up to the summit of the Feuerkogel mountain [...] Parts of the 1968 Where Eagles Dare film were shot in the Ebensee area.

Comment: Just beat me to it. Saw you posted while I was writing. Same source...